# A cypher Query fails to match properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to search on a property in Neo4j but it fails.
Here is the code:

```
==> "start n=node(*) match n.wordType = {'potent'} return n"
==>                          ^
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node:words(word='*') match n.wordType = 'potent' return n;
==> SyntaxException: failed to parse MATCH pattern
```

The properties exist and the nodes exist too.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You're typing a where clause in the match pattern. You mean:

```
start n=node(*) where n.wordType = 'potent' return n

start n=node:words(word='*') where n.wordType = 'potent' return n;
```

Better yet, you can do an index lookup:

```
start n=node:words(wordType='potent') return n;
```